# Configuring server connection with database in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am connecting to the `MS Access` server with the following code.

```
Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=162.222.225.78;Database=CRM.mdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=corpopef;Password=********;")
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
cnn.Open()
End If
cmd.Connection = cnn
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Addressbook(srno) " & _
"VALUES('" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "')"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

But it results in the following error:
**"Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.**"
Please suggest to me some methods to work around this problem.

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: The connection string seems problematic for an access database

Comment: can u plz help in connection string for access database in server..

Comment: where is the MDB file located?

Comment: try this `Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=162.222.225.78\CRM.mdb;User ID=corpopef;Password=********;")`

Comment: apart from that,insted of your connection method use this  `Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString) ... End Using`

Comment: i used this code i am getting an error saying "Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user." Plz help...

Comment: where your are getting this error ???

Comment: i recommend please use `try catch` you should write your above codes inside  a `try catch`

Comment: Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=162.222.225.78\CRM.mdb;User ID=corpopef;Password=********;") in this line..

Comment: you must definitely read [Microsoft Jet OLE DB 4.0 connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/)

Comment: i read but still i am getting the same error.. Plz help..

Comment: try this one `Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\162.222.225.78\CRM.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=yourPassword;Mode= Share Deny None")`

Comment: still i am getting the same error.. Plz help..

Comment: Are you sure you have `modify` access to the share on the server?

Comment: is this same `Data Source=\\162.222.225.78\CRM.mdb` on your current connection ??

Comment: read this [source](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeevanmurkoth/exception-cannot-start-your-application-the-workgroup-information-file-is-missing-or-opened-exclusively-by-another-user)

Comment: i not kept my database any password..

Comment: i changed this line Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=//162.222.225.78/httpdocs/App_Data/CRM.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=********;" now i am getting a error saying not a valid path..

Answer (score 1):

The connection string you used seems like an `SQL client` connection string. For an access database, you should use this format:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=*path_to_mdb_file*\CRM.MDB;User Id=*user_id*; Password=*password*;